# Are RSA keypairs proof of work?

Tags: rsa, public-key, proof-of-work

My computer generates a 65536-bit RSA keypair in 106 minutes. Is there a way to generate them faster by some trade-off? Can they be created in bulk, so long as they're able to encrypt and decrypt? Is it possible to generate large RSA keys quickly, for example by allowing the keys to be weak?

Are RSA keypairs proof of work?

Answer (score 1):

RSA keypair generation is slow because large prime numbers have to be found. Prime generation *can* be used as proof-of-work, but not on its own because one could just store a list of pre-generated primes and use those instead. You would have no way of knowing if the prime was generated on-the-fly (thus constituting "work") or if it was pre-generated a long time ago.

In fact, it would be possible to generate a large and valid multi-prime RSA modulus composed of a large number of very small, easy to find primes. It would be insecure as factoring a modulus that is the product of nothing but small primes is trivial, but it would technically create a valid keypair (i.e. all the standard RSA operations would work).

One could generate [Cunningham chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) for proof-of-work instead, which involves primality testing.

Comment: How large would a prime number have to be to take about 2 hours to find? What's the lower bound on time to generate a prime of n digits? I see there are approximations for the number of primes less than n.

Comment: @Brent Even a million digit prime number could be found in seconds if you look it up in a list of known large primes. It's also not possible to tell if a prime has been generated legitimately because it's not possible to tell _who_ generated it. And creating a typical RSA key involves finding two large primes, not just one. RSA is not a useful POW system because it's only slow when you create the key the "right" way (and there's no way for a third party to tell if you did that).